# Can I run IE 11 in Compatibility mode 10

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility

If i add a site to the compatibility list, it runs as if `IE 7`.

.. But IE 7 sucks.

The feature missing in `IE 11`, works in `IE 10`. So how do I **permanently** run all compatibility sites in `IE10` mode, not `IE7`.

I can turn it on temporary via f12 - developer console. But that is not good enough.

Comment: What version of Windows?  I know IE11 thats included in Windows 8.1 Update 1 was provided some additional Enterprise level features.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 7. Not sure what all my clients use, probably W7 as well, as i Dont think IE 11 even works on XP.

Comment: Since you are using IIE11 on Windows 7 I don't believe the Enterprise features you require to do this exist on that platform.  IE11 is not supported on `Windows XP` IE9 isn't even supported on `Windows XP`.